# Github v4 GraphQL API. Get commits by date

Tags: graphql, github-api

New to graphql and the Github API. I'm trying to get a list of commits back, sorted by date.  This is what I have so far:

```
{
  repository(owner: "facebook", name: "create-react-app") {
    ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          id
          history(first: 20) {
            pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
          }
          edges {
            node {
              messageHeadline
              oid
              message
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

This just returns a flat list of the commit history.  Is there another object or connection that I can use to group the results by date?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no notion of "groupBy" or "GroupedBy" in the [GraphQL API v4 reference](https://developer.github.com/v4/).

All you have is an [`orderBy` argument](https://platform.github.community/t/ordering-of-tags/3311/8) for [repository](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/repository/).
You can see an [example here](https://platform.github.community/t/lack-of-documentation-on-ordering-options/1477)

```
{
  organization(login: "lvtech") {
    repositories(first: 3, orderBy: {field: PUSHED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But again, that applies to repository attributes, not to commit attributes.